# MySQL - Rank user amongst list of top high-scores

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that selects the players with the top 3 highest scores in my `users` table, then creates an extra column where their rank is assigned:

```
SELECT s.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM users AS s
JOIN
( SELECT DISTINCT highscore
  FROM users
  ORDER BY highscore DESC
      LIMIT 3
) AS lim
ON s.highscore = lim.highscore 
, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY s.highscore DESC ;
```

### Current progress

So, if the table looked like this:

```
userid   name     highscore
0        sam      20
1        james    39
2        jack     10
3        harry    46
4        jennie   7
```

The result of the query would be this:

```
userid  name    highscore   rank
3       harry   46          1
1       james   39          2
0       sam     20          3
```

### Question

How could I alter this query so it also display's the user and their rank in the list of results? E.g. if `$userName = "jenny"`, how could I return:

```
userid  name    highscore   rank
3       harry   46          1
1       james   39          2
0       sam     20          3
4       jenny   7           5   <-- Add this row and skip jack
```

**Edit: I should mention - I am using MySQL version 5.0.96**

Comment: You can use a UNION

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For versions prior to 8.0...

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.*
            , @i := @i+1 i
         FROM my_table a
         JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) vars
        ORDER 
           BY highscore DESC
            , userid 
     ) x
 WHERE name = 'jennie'
    OR i <= 3
     ORDER 
        BY i;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hYsiCE1bXeTnR2HzoJkKiR/0

Comment: Thanks for this, how could I alter the query so if harry and james both had the top score of 80, both of their ranks would be `1`? In a broader sense, if two users had the same score, the rank would not increment between users?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If duplicates do happen to exist, how could I assign them the same rank? Thanks.

Comment: @CasparB Use Strawberry's approach with an additional subquery which now orders by both high score and row number.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wouldn't know how to do that - If possible, could you please elaborate on what to change, or submit an answer? Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question, or ask a new one referencing this.

Comment: @Strawberry So I've got the other half working, but the one problem with this query is that, if `jennie` is in the top 3 players, it counts her in the subselect, meaning only 3 rows will be returned. However, if she isn't in the top 3, she is added after the top 3 rows have been selected, making a total of 4 rows. I've tried for a while and can't figure out how to make the query always return 3 rows (1 of which includes jennie) - if you think you might know a way, please let me know.

Comment: OK, that's quite a different question!

Comment: @Strawberry Could you do it with a CASE clause? i.e when 'jenny' is in the top 5, it includes all `i <= 6`, instead of `i <= 5`?

Answer (score 5):

If using MySQL 8+, then the `RANK` analytic function makes this easy:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY highscore DESC) rnk
    FROM users
)

SELECT userid, name, highscore, rnk
FROM cte
WHERE rnk <= 3;
```

Comment: My database is hosted on Godaddy Linux hosting, which is only running MySQL 5.0.96, so WITH or RANK aren't recognised. Is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: The old school syntax you are using is not my forte.  Maybe someone else can help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
select * from (
(select t1.userid,t1.name,t1.highscore,@rank1:=@rank1+1 'rank' 
from (SELECT userid, name, highscore FROM users order by highscore desc) t1 
join (select @rank1:=0) r 
limit 3) 
union
(select t2.userid,t2.name,t2.highscore,t2.rank from (select t1.userid,t1.name,t1.highscore,@rank2:=@rank2+1 'rank'
from (SELECT userid, name, highscore FROM users order by highscore desc) t1 
join (select @rank2:=0) r) t2 
where t2.name='jennie')) t;
```

Comment: Hey James this works great, thanks a ton - would you have any idea how to alter it so if two users have an identical score they receive an equal rank?

Comment: for ex: if you input 'sam' instead of 'jennie' it will not show duplicate. if you need to show duplicate, change from `union` to `union all`

Comment: I meant if harry and james both had the top score of 80, how could I display the rank for both as `1`?

Comment: Currently i don't have any thought about it. Since the question was not for duplicate i have shared my knowledge.