# MySQL - Assign same rank to users with the same score

Tags: mysql

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139887/mysql-rank-user-amongst-list-of-top-high-scores) question earlier about generating a rank table that contained the top 3 scores, plus the logged-in user's score, from a list of players. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.*
            , @rank := @rank+1 rank
         FROM users a
         JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) vars
        ORDER 
           BY highscore DESC
            , userid 
     ) x
 WHERE name = 'jennie'
    OR rank <= 3
     ORDER 
        BY rank;
```

[This fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hYsiCE1bXeTnR2HzoJkKiR/0) provided by the accepted answer of my previous question demonstrates the query in use.

But, the contents of the `rank` column provided by this query are technically row numbers, not true ranks - which means when two users have the same score, they will receive different ranks. How could I give unique users with the same score equal ranks - for example, a valid result would be:

```
userid  name    highscore   rank
3       harry   50          1
1       james   50          1
0       sam     20          2
4       jenny   7           4
```

Comment: It's up to you, but I think it's more usual to store ties like this: 1,1,3,4,4,4,7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest solution to your answer I can think of is something like below

```
SELECT a.userid, a.name, a.highscore,
FIND_IN_SET( a.highscore, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( highscore ORDER BY highscore DESC) FROM my_table )) AS rank
FROM my_table a;
```

Here [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function is used to aggregate all high scores in an ordered string and after that with [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function we can locate the position of our desired score from the selected aggregated result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT highscore) FROM my_table r
WHERE s.highscore<=r.highscore) as rank
FROM my_table s
order by rank ASC
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nypySJqctEdemBAy3a3mp3/1